# how to open visual studio 2015 IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I installed `Visual Studio Community 2015` from https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx, but I don't see an option to open the IDE?

Attached a screen shot, I see command line options but no IDE, how do I open IDE?

[image: Visualstudiocommunity2015]

Comment: The shortcut to Visual Studio is created "loose" in the Start Menu, instead of in the Visual Studio 2015 folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is located in the:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE"
```

folder. The name of the executable is `devenv.exe`. Yes, the name of the `.exe` is not `Visual Studio`, it is `devenv.exe` - which might sometimes cause confusion. So the full path would be:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

Also, unlike previous `Visual Studio`, the `Visual Studio` folder from the start menu does not show the application. You could find `Visual Studio 2015` executable directly, not under the `Visual Studio` folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for visual studio 2015, you don't go in the Visual Studio 2015 folder under accessories as you can already see why.

Just type Visual Studio 2015 and only then the visual studio icon comes up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015 shortcut not in `Visual Studio 2015` folder

[image: this is windows 10 system]

Visual Studio 2015 startup file:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"`